# Performing a calculation to show Python has 53-bit precision

Tags: python, math, bit, scientific-computing

May anyone provide guidance on how to perform a simple calculation in Python to roughly prove that the language implements 53 bit precision, as per IEEE 754? I don't have much to go on here other than this. I have tried to work off of the canonical example of 0.1 + 0.2, but no luck.

Comment: 53 bit precision?  Not on a 64 bit floating point number.  53 digits?  Yes, but only 15-17 bits of precision.  They aren't the same thing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: I apologize, I did not intend to twist the language.

Comment: You did more than twist the language - you agreed that your purpose is incorrect.  You won't get more than 15-17 digits of precision.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> for i in range(100):
    x = 2**i
    if float(x) == float(x + 1):
        print(i)
        break

53
```

This works because `x` is an integer, and integers are unlimited in their bit range in Python.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the epsilon, such that `1.0 + eps == 1.0`:

```
from itertools import count
eps = 1.0
for bits in count():
    if 1.0+eps == 1.0:
        break
    eps *= 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a third example to the mix.

In IEEE 754, infinity is defined as setting all exponent bits to one
and all mantissa bits to to zero. With negative 
infinity, the sign bit is also set to one. This means that the only zero bits will belong to the mantissa.

```
import struct

def float_bin(f):
    "as bin function, but converts floats to their binary representation"
    bytes_ = struct.pack("d", f)
    format_ = "{:08b}" * len(bytes_)
    binary = format_.format(*bytes_[::-1])
    return binary

mantissa_bits = float_bin(float("-inf"))
# mantissa_bits == "1111111111110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
print(mantissa_bits.count("0")) # prints 52... (rather than 53)
```

Where is the last bit? IEEE 754 clearly specifies 53 bits for the mantissa, but only 52 are stored. This is because the leading bit of the mantissa is implied.
All numbers expressed in scientific notation must start with a
non-zero digit. For instance, `0.123 * 10^5` is not valid. Instead, the correct representation is `1.23 * 10^4`.
However, since there is only one non-zero digit in binary, then there is only one value this bit could ever take. As such it would be a waste to store this bit explicitly. Meaning, for a 53-bit mantissa, you only need to store 52-bits.